# In CiscoAMP can one determine how long the scan of a file took based on the times between scans in history.db?

Tags: antivirus

We need to prove to our corporate security that scans in AMP are hurting our business.

I found the following old documentation on FireAMP, which seems to indicate you can extract information on what files have been scanned; and I'm thinking that maybe I'll be able to sort it by datetime and determine how long it took to scan a file; and maybe based on that we can get Corporate to exclude scanning a particular file that is eating up all our CPU time; is that reasonable?

https://web.archive.org/web/20170702192937/http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/advanced-malware-protection-endpoints/118802-technote-fireamp-00.html

In the past there have been log files that it scanned on a server, and it was causing all sorts of timeouts, which effected our revenue.

Is this reasonable?  Am I thinking straight?